# Building webpage: Possible to take input from an HTML form and use it as input into a Python function?

Tags: python, html, cherrypy

Trying to build a webpage.

I would like to be able to take some user input from an HTML form, run a python function on that input, and spit out some output back to the user.

Example: users input '2' into the HTML form, the python function doubles it and returns '4' on the webpage (my actual function uses matrix algebra so unlikely I could do it all in jQuery).

I'm using cherrypy but I am open to other modules. I'm at a loss as to how to go about doing this as most cherrypy examples just print a string without actually calling any python functions.

Comment: What about http://docs.cherrypy.org/dev/intro/tutorial/tutorial.html#receiving-data-from-html-forms ?

Comment: Are you at all familiar with django or will that be an overkill?